# Cross-installing a package for a different distribution

Tags: kernel, apt, cross-compilation

I have a piece of (ARM64) hardware running a linux kernel and I'd like to put the aplay utility on it to test audio. The hardware does not have a network connection, and is not running the same kernel/environment as my dev machine.

Is there a way to tell apt what I'm installing for, and download everything so that I can tar it up, transfer over USB, and then untar and install somehow (I don't have a package manager at all on there, so I'd need a dpkg or equivalent). Is this possible?

Alternatively, are there any super-light audio players so I can just cross-compile?

For argument's sake, this is a Renesas R-Car H3 board running their 3.9 kernel. Network unfortunately isn't an option.

Comment: It looks like you need to rebuild your image. It is possible to replace your current install on your board at this time?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I may be able to rebuild the rootfs, but I do not have the source for the kernel

Comment: From a cursory search it appears that it is common with R-Car boards is to rebuild the entire OS with the drivers and all the software you require then flash it back to the eMMC/SD card. If you can mount the filesystem you may be able to add the software without rebuild but you would need to update your post to include what your development environment is (OS and version, etc). so people can better provide instructions on how to do so. [This is what I have found so far](https://elinux.org/R-Car/Boards/Yocto-Gen3-ADAS) but this site mentions that your board should include documentation.

Comment: Thanks - there's a reason it's "for argument's sake" as it's not exactly my situation, just the closest example I can use

Comment: I see, so it is not an R-Car H3 board? It is going to be hard to answer your question without the specifics of your issue. If you could please update your post with what the problem is, what you have tried so far and what is not working including all of your relevant hardware and software, it will be much easier to get an answer for you. Thank you